# java.util.logging.Logger : is a default log file created?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

By default, the logger outputs log records to standard error stream (System.err). Similarly, does it also outputs the log records to a file? 
If yes, then what is the location of that file?

Comment: No. You have to [configure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19717-01/819-7753/gcblo/index.html) it to log to a file.

Answer (score 0):

The default logging properties file is located in your JDK under jre/lib.  You'll have to modify this file by un-commenting this line:

```
 #handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

A little further down the file you'll see the file handler properties.  These will dictate where the file is saved, how much data it can store, how many files should be created, etc.

```
 java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/java%u.log
 java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
 java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
 java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
```

For more info here's [some documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19717-01/819-7753/gcblo/index.html).

Edit: For clarification on location: the %h in the path indicates your home directory.

Comment: I don't want to use that file. I have my own configuration file which specifies the path to the log file. My question is, if I comment this line will the logger create a log file by default?

Comment: If you don't have a FileHandler defined, it will not send the log to a file.